# Number of lattice paths

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, integer-lattices

In my notes I have this:

A lattice path is path consisting of step points $(x_0,y_0),(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_m,y_m).$  where either

$x_{i+1}=x_{i}$ and $y_{i+1}=y_i+1$

or $x_{i+1}=x_{i}+1$ and $y_{i+1}=y_i$.

If in a lattice path , $x_i \gt y_i$ $\forall i$ except $i=0$ or $i=m,$we say path is a good path ,otherwise a bad path.. 
[image]

After that I can't understand this:

then it is written that total no. of paths are: $\binom{x_m+y_m-x_0-y_0}{x_m-x_0}$,

Please help how to arrive at this formula ....

---

> **EDIT**:I got answer for total no. of paths but can't understand this:
>
> Book says to find Bad path consider this:
>
> Let $\tau$ be a path from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(x_m,y_m)$ ,$\tau$ is a bad path so it touches line $y=x$ .
>
> Let $\tau=\tau_1+\tau_2$
>
> $\tau_1$ is path from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(i,i)$,and
>
> $\tau_2$ is path from $(i,i)$ to $(x_m,y_m)$.Take $\tau_1'$ =reflection of $\tau_1$ about $y=x$ .
>
> $\tau'=\tau_1'+\tau_2$ is path from $(y_0,x_0)$ to $(x_m,y_m)$.
>
> So,there is 1-1 correspondence between bad paths from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(x_m,y_m)$
>   by $\tau=\tau'$.
>
> Bad paths are all paths from $(y_0,x_0)$ to $(x_m,y_m)$ =$\binom{x_m+y_m-x_0-y_0}{x_m-y_0}$
>
> But I can't still understand
>
> - how to conclude that Bad paths are all paths from $(y_0,x_0)$ to $(x_m,y_m)$ .

Please help....

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hint: The technique in your example is called [Andre's reflection principle](http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/ballotproblem/monthly358-363-renault.pdf). An example with reflection at the diagonal (and ties allowed!) can be found in [Bertrand's ballot theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem).

**Added 2014-10-04:** according to comment below of @spectraa

> The idea is to *construct a bijection* between the *bad pathes* and *all pathes starting in $(y_0,x_0)$* end ending in $(x_m,y_m)$.

We have following situation:

> Startvalue $A=(x_0,y_0)$ is *below* the diagonal $y=x$, since $x_0 > y_0$
>
> Endvalue $B=(x_m,y_m)$ is *below* the diagonal $y=x$, since $x_m > y_0$
>
> All pathes are the pathes containing $(1,0)$-steps or $(0,1)$-steps from $A$ to $B$
>
> Good pathes are the pathes from $A$ to $B$ which are *below* the diagonal $y=x$
>
> Bad pathes are all pathes from $A$ to $B$, which are not good pathes.

We observe:

> - A bad path is a path from $A$ to $B$ which touches (or crosses) the diagonal $y=x$.
> - Let's say a bad path $p$ touches (or crosses) the diagonal (the first time!) at $Z=(z,z)$
> - We *reflect* this bad path at the diagonal $y=x$ and get a path $\overline{p}$ starting at $\overline{A}=(y_0,x_0)$, which touches (or crosses) the diagonal $y=x$ the first time at $Z$ and ends in $B$.

Now the following holds:

> - *All* reflected pathes of bad pathes have the property that they start at $\overline{A}$ and end in $B$.
> - Since $\overline{A}=(y_0,x_0)$ with $y_0 > x_0$ *all reflected pathes* have to cross the diagonal in order to reach $B$.
>
> This is so because $B=(x_m,y_m)$ with $x_m > y_m$ and therefore along a *reflected bad path* we walk through a point $Z^\prime$ with $x$-value equal $y$-value.

On the other hand:

> Since *all pathes* starting in $\overline{A}$ and ending in $B$ have to *cross the diagonal* in order to reach $B$. Therefore they themselves can be reflected at the diagonal. After reflection they:
>
> - start in $A$
> - touch (or cross) the diagonal and
> - end in $B$.
>
> So they are a *bad path*.

**Conclusion** There is a bijection between the bad pathes and those pathes starting in the reflected point $\overline{A}$ and ending in $B$, therefore the number of them is equal.

Comment: my doubt is only with the step in question that how did we conclude that Bad paths are all paths from $(y_0,x_0)$ to $(x_m,y_m)$ ..........

Comment: @spectraa: I've added some notes in my answer. Hope it helps! :-) Regards.

Comment: thanks a lot the answer is clear to me now...

Comment: Great! And thanks for the bounty! :-)

Answer (score 7):

The discussion about good/bad paths seems to have no relevance to the question, so let's ignore that.

We can assume WLOG that $x_0 = y_0 = 0$. Now, any path from $(0,0)$ to $(x_m,y_m)$ satisfying your condition will have length $x_m+y_m$. At each vertex you have the choice between going up or to the right, and you know that at exactly $x_m$ points, you'll have to go to the right to end up in $(x_m,y_m)$. This is the only condition though: a path is given by choosing which $x_m$ of the $x_m+y_m$ of the points will be the points after which you head to the right. There are exactly $\binom{x_m+y_m}{x_m}$ such choices.